# MySQL count all items, aggregate less than as others

Tags: mysql, pie-chart, summarization

I need to fetch data from many mysql 5.6 tables to create a pie chart.  As you know,  the pie chart is useful if it represents meaningful data.  However when you have many non meaningful data points, say less than .. or non important values,  the pie chart becomes unclear.    I need to count the occurrence of each category and aggregate the not significant counts, less than X,  as OTHERS.

At the moment I make a

```
Select category, count(*) as total from table_name group by category.
```

It gives me each category and it's counts.  How can I get the categories whose totals are over 50 and the ones that are below,  get summarized under "Others".  Thanks,  Jorge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(total > 50, category, 'Others') AS category, SUM(total) AS total
FROM (SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM table_name
      GROUP BY category) AS subquery
GROUP BY category
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to summarize all categories with less than 4 entries:

```
select category, count(*) as total from table_name group by category having count(*) >= 4

union

select 'others', sum(c) as total from (
  select category, count(*) c from table_name group by category having count(*) < 4
) tmp
```